# DELETE / TRUNCATE queries causing tables to become inaccessible

Tags: mysql, database, python-2.7

I have a problem with a few (3) tables in my database, they respond to nothing at all. They are coincidentally the only tables where I perform DELETE and TRUNCATE queries on. The rest of the tables in the database work fine and have no issues whatsoever. With a 'corrupt' table I cannot do any of the following:

- Browse the Rows / Structure in PHPmyadmin or Navicat (the corrupt tables are very small). After 30 seconds the error 'MySQL server has gone away' appears.
- Truncate / Drop the table, either through PHPmyadmin, Python or Navicat. The same MySQL server has gone away error appears after a while (2 attempts shown below).

  ```
  Got a MySQL error (2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query) on the following query: drop table scrape_allocations2
  Got a MySQL error (2006: MySQL server has gone away) on the following query: drop table scrape_allocations2
  ```
- Repair / Check / Optimise the table OR database also hangs forever and has no effect.
- Creating a backup of the database hangs on the table and fails.
- Any other query (SELECT, INSERT, etc.) doing literally anything to this table does not work either and fails with the same error.

Two of these tables show intermittent issues, so they have this problem but after a few hours they are fine again. One table appears to be in this state permanently. When it first happened two weeks ago I just created a new table with the same job and left the old table there, but now after two weeks the new table has the same issue (After about a week the old table became accessible again and I dropped it).

The table in question is a very small table where several scripts simultaneously perform INSERT, SELECT and DELETE queries every night. Each row is an allocation of a partition of data so each script knows what the other running scripts are doing and they don't run the same partition twice. When the partition is complete by a script it deletes the row from the table. This works perfectly until the table somehow becomes corrupted.

At first I assumed there was some kind of lock on the table, but when I check SHOW PROCESSLIST there are no processes there and SHOW OPEN TABLES has nothing in_use or name_locked.

Since it's a web hosted database I don't have access to the my.cnf file and I can't restart the database in recovery mode. I do have a SSH login but I get access denied when trying to edit the my.cnf file or restart the database. Also, the main tables of the database with many millions of rows work perfectly fine and have never shown any of these issues.

This is the only code that interacts with the 'corrupt' tables, using Python (running 5+ times simultaneously on different servers each night):

```
def select_partition():
    global results

''' This is the main method, which does the following:
    1. Selects all unscraped partitions from the scrape list and checks for each partition whether
       another scraper has already allocated it.
    2. If a partition has not been allocated yet the scraper allocates the partition.
    3. Fetches all users from the scrape list belonging to the partition. Then,
       makes the HTTP request for each username. Finally, it processes the results of all requests.
    4. Deallocates the partition, repeat steps 1-3.
    5. If no partitions are left, the script stops. '''

    #1
    partitions = execute_query('SELECT partitionID FROM scrape_{0} WHERE partitionID != 0 GROUP BY partitionID'.format(TYPE))

    for partition in partitions:
    allocated = execute_query('SELECT partitionID FROM scrape_allocations2 WHERE partitionID = {0}'.format(partition[0]))

    #2
    if not allocated:
        allocation = execute_query('INSERT INTO scrape_allocations2 VALUES ({0},\'{1}\',\'{2}\')'.format(partition[0],SCRAPER_NAME,datetime.datetime.now()))
        if allocation:
            print 'Selected and allocated partition {0}. Starting to fetch the skill data now. Total time spent so far: {1} seconds'.format(partition[0],str(round(time.time() - start_time,1)))

            #3
            user_list = execute_query('SELECT userID, userName FROM scrape_{1} WHERE partitionID = {0}'.format(partition[0],TYPE))
            if user_list:
                make_requests(user_list,partition[0])
                process_results(results,build_user_dict(user_list),partition[0])

            #4
            execute_query('DELETE FROM scrape_allocations2 WHERE partitionID = {0}'.format(partition[0]),False)
            results = []
            count_fetch = 0
        return True

    #5
    print 'There are no more partitions to scrape. Stopping now.'
    return False

def execute_query(query):
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        db.commit()

        if query.split(' ')[0].upper() == 'SELECT':
            return cursor.fetchall()

        return True

    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        try: print 'Got a MySQL error ({1}: {2}) on the following query: {0}'.format(query,e.args[0],e.args[1])
        except IndexError: 'Got a MySQL error ({1}: {2}) on the following query: {0}'.format(query,e)

# Main loop
while things_to_do:
    things_to_do = select_partition()
```

Some additional information:

Server version: 10.0.20-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server

Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev

Comment: This might be better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ (although carefully learn about the community there, I'm not sure about their guidelines for what's an on-topic question).